# Should I go to the office of a company to discuss a project without appointment?

Tags: professionalism, communication, ethics

I'm still a French student, preparing an examination at master level which requires to build a small project with an industrial company. But my situation is becoming really taut: examinations are coming and I still don't have company to work with (totally my fault). However, I've found one really interesting: near me, working exactly in my field of competence, small enough (a SOHO), …

The problem is, that they don't answer to my emails. I've called them, to check if they have received my email, but the answer was like "probably my secretary have received it, I'll ask her to give you an answer". Nothing since this date.

I really want to accelerate the process, and I intend more and more to go directly to their office to discuss. Is that conceivable without seeming rude? If not, what can I do instead?

Comment: I would more go along the route of calling the secretary and making an appointment if possible, possibly book for a 15-30 minute pitch to see if the person/company is interested, going in might seem rude and come off as saying your schedule is more important than theirs.

Comment: Dear downvoter, how can I improve my question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Showing up at any office without an appointment is at best rude - you didn't ask for permission to show up let alone alone work out the logistics of showing up - and disruptive. Again, nobody expected you to show up when you did and now, someone has to drop whatever they are doing and deal with your intrusion. At worst, it is suicidal because you may have created enough ill will to doom your prospects with this prospective employer, unless you are unusually good at turning up the charm. Some people are, I'm not :)

If they are interested in you, they already know how to contact you. If they are REALLY interested in you, you'd never get a chance to ask your question on this site because you'd already be working with them :) Employers work according to their own timetable not yours and are focused on their own convenience not your needs. And in my experience, if a prospective employer is not interested in me, the silence will be deafening.  At least, in 95% of the cases.

> Follow-up comment from @Blackhole "So basically, you're saying I'm already out? Ouch, exams will be pretty difficult this year :P. Is there nothing I can do? Calling and making an appointment, as proposed by TheOneWhoPrograms? The fact is, they're not really an "employer", as I wouldn't be paid at all for my work."

"Ne pas mettre tous les oeufs dans le meme panier" Don't put all your eggs in the same basket :) Cast a wide net, set up a fishing line in every spot. It's horribly time and energy consuming but looking for a job can be a job in itself - Bonne chance :)

Comment: So basically, you're saying I'm already out? Ouch, exams will be pretty difficult this year :P. Is there nothing I can do? Calling and making an appointment, as proposed by [TheOneWhoPrograms](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/25765/can-i-go-to-the-office-of-a-company-to-discuss-without-appointment/25769#comment65010_25765)? The fact is, they're not really an "employer", as I wouldn't be paid at all for my work.

Comment: @Blackhole "Ne pas mettre tous les oeufs dans le meme panier"  Don't put all your eggs in the same basket :) Cast a wide net, set up a fishing line in every spot. It's horribly time and energy consuming but looking for a job can be a job in itself - Bonne chance :)

Comment: @blackhole - If the company has not acknowledged you then it is likely not interested in doing a project with you,  Is there some reason that you think that they would besides just that you want to work with them?

Answer (score 2):

This is a company you are hoping to do a project with, not at company you are looking for a job with. Their lack of interest in you may be because they lack interest (for any number of reasons, like they are just too busy) or because they did not take the time to really understand what you were proposing (again, probably too busy).

You need to know whether this company is a possibility for you and you need to know soon, so I think you have nothing to lose by showing up. Be prepared to be quick with your explanations. Have copies of a proposal you can leave if they show any interest.

Salespeople make cold calls like this all the time, and often it does not go well (because busy companies don't like interruptions), however, occasionally it does go well. If it goes badly, at least you will know and can quit wasting your time in the hopes of doing a project with them.

Your pitch could go something like:
"Hello, I'm Jacque LaFitte, and I am a student at XYZ. I was hoping to talk to someone for a few minutes about a project I am doing for school based on your company." Gently push for the name of someone you could talk to and the best way to reach them. Take the name of the person you speak to first and invoke it in any future conversations with others ("Marie gave me your name as someone who could help me...").

You might get lucky and find someone who went to your school or who believes in helping students! Good luck!